# Leapp upgrade fails despite plenty of disk space available

Tags: centos, leapp

When using Leapp to upgrade from CentOS 7 to Rocky 8 it successfully passed the preupgrade check.
During the upgrade itself it keeps failing with errors about needing at least 1085MB more space on the
/ filesystem.
Currently the / filesystem is 19% full and has 29G available, only 6.6G used.
The /var filesystem is 36% full and has 8.5G available, only 4.6G used (i increased it to this because the preupgrade kept failing on /var/lib/leapp space.)

Does leapp make some bad assumptions or calculations that it thinks it doesnt have enough space?

I increased the space on / and /var to three times the amount used.

Comment: Hello @Davep75 I have a similar case, moving from Oracle Linux 7 to 8. It tells me that 30 MB are missing.

I see that the usual recommendation is to run export LEAPP_OVL_SIZE=8192, only in my case it makes no difference; I have the same error.

I have moved the /var/lib/leapp folder to the root, /leapp then made a symbolic link; executed and got the same error.

I have removed previous kernels, deleted logs older than 2 days, uninstall unneeded packages and still have the same message with the 30 MB.

Answer (score 1):

The issue which you have mentioned appeared for me during the time of migrating my CentOS7.9 to Rocky8.

I was able to fix this issue by increasing the /var size to approximately 8G.

I suggest you try increasing your /var disk space to 10G and rerun the upgrade.

If that doesn't work, you may try the other solution mentioned in https://almalinux.discourse.group/t/upgrade-from-centos-7-x-to-alma-8-5-with-leapp/1233/6